# Eclipse - Android UI Design extremely laggy

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface

While I am designing Android Views, Eclipse starts to lag horribly. This happens as soon as I set one of the view element's properties. It is really making me miserable.

I'm using the 64bit Eclipse on Windows 7 64bit. Just in case it is relevant, I'm using the Android 2.1 SDK. It also happens in the 2.2 SDK.

Any advice is welcome.

Regards,
EZFrag

Comment: The OS is pretty much irrelevant. What's your CPU and how much memory does Eclipse have available? It likes memory. A lot of it.

Comment: Well, my MAC mini has got 2 gig RAM. And eclipse is purring like a kitten on it. My Windows machine have 5 gig, and eclipse is lagging horribly on it. Why am I using the Windows machine? It's a laptop, so I can pretty much work where ever , whenever I want to.(and the MAC mini is in for repairs. Again... oh, thy fragile logic boards)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to play around with the eclipse.ini JVM argument.

For example here is my current eclipse configuration.

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    1024m
    -vmargs
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
    -Xms512m
    -Xmx1024m
    -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Comment: I would definitely recommend that.

Comment: Ok, I applied the settings. Will let it run for a day or to and let you know

Comment: Ok, it seems to be okish. For now, this is the best solution I have. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's sounds like offtopic, but... Write layout xml by hand. This way gives you better understanding of your layout.

Comment: Oh,I understand the XML layout perfectly, its just that my screens isn't usually complicated, and it goes a lot faster to drag everything in place than coding it by hand